# How to start multiple instances of GoogleDriveFS

Tags: google-backup-and-sync

GoogleDriveSync can start up to 3 times concurrently and thus sync 3 different Google User Accounts to different paths on a Windows system. I want to use GoogleDriveFS instead and do the same: start three instances at the same time and configure each with a different Google Drive Login. How and where can I configure that? When I click a second time on the desktop item while one instance is already running, it will display an error message that Google Drive is already executing.

Comment: Without any background.. my first inclination is to run multiple instances under multiple OS accounts.  There is no way for their API to know the difference unless they are tracking you by IP address (which I doubt).

Comment: Yes, that works. But I want it to run under the same user account, just like Backup&Sync

Answer (score 0):

According to Google support chat, it is not possible. GDFS only supports one account, one has to manually log out and in to service a different account.